# How to test if the method requested was POST or not using old JS method in API(Postman)

Tags: javascript, api

I have a task to test in Postman https://swapi.dev/api/people if the method requested was
POST or not using old JS method

Comment: Be more clear. What you are trying to do and what have you got ?

Comment: I need to write test on the old JS method in Postman like: tests["Body contains user_id"] = responsebody.has("user_id"); I want to clarify that this is POST by this test